# Call function after two promises resolve in angularJS, one using result from other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

In a controller function, I make some operations:

- Get a list of organizations with a promise
- In the then of this promise, I loop through each of them to extract some data and populate some of my controller attributes.
- One of this operation is to call another promise to gather all users attached to this organization, with a loop inside of it to extract name and other stuff.
- When I get ALL of it, so every organization has been parsed, and within them all users too, I must call a function to update my view.

I got it working by setting some flags (`orgParsed` and `usersParsed`) but I find it to be... a code shame.

I heard about a way of maybe doing this by using `$q` to wait for the two promises and maybe loops inside their "`then`" to be resolve before calling my view function. But I struggle applying this code change since the second promise use the result of the first to gather the organization ID.

Here is my current code:

```
this.getOrgData = function () {
    return Service.getList().then(function (result) {
        var orgCount = result.Objects.length;
        var orgParsed = 0;

        _.forEach(result.Objects, function (org) {  
            org.Users = [];

            // Some logic here using 'org' data

            Service.getUsers(org.Id, 0, 0).then(function (userResult) {                        
                usersParsed = 0;

                _.forEach(userResult.Objects, function (user) {
                    // Some Logic here using 'user.Name'            
                    usersParsed++;                         
                });
                orgParsed++;

                if (orgParsed === orgCount && usersParsed === userResult.Objects.length) {
                    self.sortMenuList(); // My view Function
                }
            });
        });
        $scope.$broadcast("getOrgData");
    });
};
```

Do you see any way to trigger my self.sortMenuList() function only when I can be sure I got all users of every companies parsed in more elegant/efficient/safe way?

Comment: What do you need `usersParsed` for? And what's `doneUsers`?

Comment: $q.all() is the*angular way* of waiting for the results of multiple endpoint calls

Comment: doneUsers was a mistake.Question corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that counting should definitely be replaced by `$q.all`, especially as you did not bother to handle any errors.

```
this.getOrgData = function () {
    return Service.getList().then(function (result) {
        $scope.$broadcast("getOrgData"); // not sure whether you want that here before the results from the loop
        return $q.all(_.map(result.Objects, function (org) {  
            org.Users = [];
            // Some logic here using 'org' data
            return Service.getUsers(org.Id, 0, 0).then(function (userResult) {
                _.forEach(userResult.Objects, function (user) {
                    // Some Logic here using 'user.Name' 
                });
            });
        }));
    }).then(function() {
       self.sortMenuList(); // My view Function;
    })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you describe sounds like you want to wait until a certain amount of promises are all resolved, and then do something with the result. That's really easy when you use `Promise.all()`:

```
this.getOrgData = function () {
    return Service.getList().then(function (result) {
        var promises = [];

        _.forEach(result.Objects, function (org) {  
            org.Users = [];

            // Some logic here using 'org' data

            // Store the promise for this user in the promises array
            promises.push(Service.getUsers(org.Id, 0, 0));
        });


        // userResults is an array of all the results of the promises, in the same order as the getUsers was called
        Promise.all(promises).then(function (userResults) {
            _.forEach(userResults, function(userResult) {                        
                _.forEach(userResult.Objects, function (user) {
                    // Some Logic here using 'user.Name'            
                });
            });

            self.sortMenuList();
        });

        $scope.$broadcast("getOrgData");
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks, very usefull but I'll go with `$q.all`